# Cannot get value from behind code to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

When I call the function from the javascript, I using this one:

```
PageMethods.pumpValue(signupname.value, signuppassword1.value, signupemail.value, signupnumber.value)
```

on my behind code I using this one:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function pumpValue(user As String, password As String, email As String, contact As String) As Boolean
end function
```

In the end I got the undefined even I return the true, can I get the value from the web method of the vb?

Comment: What is PageMethods? Is that your MVC controller class?

Comment: i using this from the javascript to call behind code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're referring to your UI controls properly. Currently, you're passing `signupname.value`. Try `document.getElementById('signupname').value`. The same goes for the other UI controls.

Also, make sure you're passing `onSuccess` and `onFailure` references when calling your `PageMethods` function. In the `onSuccess` function, you can pass the return value and use it. For example:

```
function onSuccess(resultFromVB){
    alert(resultFromVB); //this will show true or false from your server side function
}
```

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: @RyanShine Then elaborate on the issue. I know for a fact that this will work. I just did the exact same thing in a project of my own. If I have missed something, please fill me in. I'd be glad to help.